# How does one "get rekt"?

Tags: meaning, slang

I often see people write "get rekt" to someone when that person makes a mistake or when they beat the person to a goal. It's not immediately obvious what this is intended to mean. I assume "rekt" is Internet speak for "wrecked," but why should someone seek out being wrecked if they've lost at something? What does this Internet colloquialism actually mean?

Comment: In *my* vernacular, getting ***wrecked*** is what happens if you ingest [too] many intoxicants.

Comment: I don't remember seeing "get rekt", I do remember seeing "rekt" and "got rekt" for describing catastrophic failure to perform.

Comment: @FumbleFingers So telling someone to "get rekt" would be like telling them to get drunk?

Comment: I agree with @FumbleFingers that it can be used that way. In fact, I've heard it used that way (only in speech).

Comment: @Amadan Neither have I encountered "get rekt". But "rekt/got rekt" doesn't referred to catastrophic failure to perform but to catastrophic defeat - which could, in principle be, be coupled with decent performance overpowered by opponent's excellence.

Comment: @pythonian29033: Despite the fact that I agree with you, I feel compelled to post an answer to put this one to bed.

Comment: It's *slang*.  It's not supposed to be perfectly logical.

Comment: @Alex: Given the point noted at the end of my answer, it might not be too fanciful to suppose that at least *some* people who use *Get rekt!* as a "brush-off" are conflating *rekt -> wrecked -> soundly beaten* with *I got beaten = I **lost***, and hence they conflate *Get rekt! -> Go away! - > Fuck off! -> **Get lost!***

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***Get rekt*** comes from ***Get wrecked***. See [here](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=get%20rekt).

Telling someone to "get wrecked" (in the context of a game) can be similar to telling someone to "go kill yourself." Implicit in the imperative is that the person it's directed at is so bad or that the commentator hates them so much that they ought to just go kill or wreck themselves.

Of course, as is common with slang, it is often used with heavy amounts of irony or non-seriousness.

It can also be used as a standard imperative instructing the interlocutor to get wrecked or destroyed. The slight irony here is that you give the imperative after the wrecking has already happened.

Comment: I'd like to emphasize that this is almost never meant as literally "go kill yourself". Sorta like the (more modern?) "kys", it's using hyperbole to say "wow you're bad". I think most of my friends who use "get rekt" -- including me, because I'm trash -- would very much disavow any meaning suggesting suicide.

Comment: Yeah I think the analogy to "go kill yourself" is only accurate at the abstractest levels, where any and all baggage/associations of "kill yourself" are gone. Another way to understand it is that the imperative form can be meant as a **funny play on expected grammar** - sometimes the meaning is just "you got wrecked" or "I just wrecked you", but and the unexpected grammatical form is just funny of you don't get too tangled up in trying to understand it literally.

Answer (score 6):

Explained well by [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=get+rekt+m8&defid=8116784)

**Get rekt m8**

> Mostly used after getting good kill or shot, in mostly FPS (1st person shooter) 
> Rekt is a misspelled version of the word "Wrecked". M8 is meant to be M + Eight = Mate. So it's get wrecked mate
>
> *360 degrees headshot with a sniper rifle without even aiming in some random Call of Duty game (also 360 noscope)*.
>
> Me: Ha get rekt m8.
>
> Victim: bwahahahaa, im such a noob

If you want to see the Xfactor judges **get rekt** have a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f4EwKrTgtLQ

EDIT:
**Get wrecked** per se, means get injured or beat up. See [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=get+wrecked&defid=4991972) again.

Comment: This doesn't really explain what "getting wrecked" means though.

Answer (score 3):

I think we can trust the entry in [knowyourmeme.com](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/rekt) on this one...

> “***Rekt***”, also known as ***#rekt***, is an Internet slang term which is shorthand for “***wrecked***,” which is often used in online gaming to indicate that someone has been defeated or embarassed, in a similar vein to the term [“pwned”](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/owned-pwned).
>   **Origin**
>   On June 6th, 2011, [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=rekt) user PossiblyCouldOKIWill submitted an entry for the term “rekt,” defining it as text message slang for the term “wrecked”:
>   *“Text for “wrecked”, as sooo drunk you’ve forgotten your name but can just about type a text to your mate whose missed called you"*
>   **Spread**
>   On October 13th, 2012, World of [Warcraft Forums](http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/search?q=rekt) member Balrogboogie started a thread titled “Get Rekt Ally Scrublords.” On October 13th, 2013, Tale Worlds Forums[4](http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/search?q=rekt) member Unicorn submitted a thread about the “REKT” North American Dueling tournament for the role-playing game Mount and Blade. On October 31st, Twitter user @SSoHPKC tweeted his idea for a Halloween prank accompanied by the phrase “Get reKt.” Within the following four months, the tweet gathered more than 490 favorites and 440 retweets.

---

Note that *wrecked = (very) drunk* is primarily a *British* usage, so most likely the vast majority of people using *rekt* in recent years aren't familiar with that sense. They simply see it as a "cute" way of writing a word that means *destroyed* (figuratively, *totally defeated* in online games, etc.).

Comment: 1 up for urban dictionary reference! Why the question had to absolutely be posted here before googling, which would inevitably lead to Urban Dictionary, is beyond me.

Comment: @pythonian29033: Well, there *is* a lot of complete garbage on UD. But per my first sentence above, I have quite a bit of faith in *knowyourmeme* (and the even more extensive [*tvtropes*](http://tvtropes.org/)) for this sort of thing. But I warn you that if you follow that link you're likely to slip into a timewarp and not resurface for some considerable time.

Answer (score 2):

In regards to the other answers, they have given (from what I have read) a non-gamer response.

Their response's are correct, but in, I believe the way you're asking, the term "get rekt" would mean the person saying it just "killed" or "beat" etc.. in whatever it is/was they are doing.

Basically, its a term for saying  you just lost.

Comment: Agreed. When used unironically, this phrase is only used by the victor to taunt the loser.